# Magento2: Module Vault rest api help

Tags: module, api, rest-api, magento2.2.4, vault

I have created a webapi.xml in module vault:

```
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">

    <route url="/V1/vault/items" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Vault\Api\PaymentTokenManagementInterface" method="getListByCustomerId"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="self" />
        </resources>
        <data>
            <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
        </data>
    </route>


</routes>
```

Give this type of error :-

> `this is a result:"message": "Internal Error. Details are available in
>   Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-5b7c371e39aa0" }`

in my log file i see this error: -

```
Error:
main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5b7c371e39aa0; Message: Class \Magento\Vault\Api\Data\PaymentTokenSearchResultsInterfa does not exist {"exception":"     
     [object] (Exception(code: -1): Report ID: webapi-5b7c371e39aa0; Message: Class      \\Magento\\Vault\\Api\\Data\\PaymentTokenSearchResultsInterfa does not exist at /<dir>/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:205, ReflectionException(code: -1): Class \\Magento\\Vault\\Api\\Data\\PaymentTokenSearchResultsInterfa does not exist at /<dir>/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/MethodsMap.php:155)"} []
```

Can help me?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is an issue in Magento 2 core.

```
/**
 * Lists payment tokens that match specified search criteria.
 *
 * @param int $customerId Customer ID.
 * @return \Magento\Vault\Api\Data\PaymentTokenSearchResultsInterface Payment token search result interface.
 * @since 100.1.0
 */
public function getListByCustomerId($customerId);
```

return value is `\Magento\Vault\Api\Data\PaymentTokenSearchResultsInterface` but actually it returns `\Magento\Vault\Api\Data\PaymentTokenInterface[]`. So set correct return type fix the issue.

Here you can check working sample https://github.com/troublediehard/mma-customapi

Answer (score 0):

We needed to import tokens into the vault using the rest Api, so we knocked this module together: https://packagist.org/packages/zero1/vault-web-api hopefully it helps.